# How to fix Ctrl and Shift problems in games?

Tags: shortcut-keys, games

I often had trouble with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifiers while playing games (maybe this is gnome specific).
For example if I press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to crouch and I press <kbd>3</kbd> to select some gun while crouching I get in game menu (which is triggered by <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove bindings (keys will still work in game)

```
xmodmap -e 'remove Control = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'remove shift = Shift_L'
```

add bindings back again after you are done playing game

```
xmodmap -e 'add Control = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'add shift = Shift_L'
```